# Android home screen widget documentation

Tags: android, android-widget

Do you know any books, articles, examples, screencasts that document how to develop an home screen widget on Android?

I just found these links:

- [widget design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html)
- [Introducing home screen widgets and
  the AppWidget framework](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/introducing-home-screen-widgets-and.html)

I would like to develop a tiny home screen ticker and I'm searching for the proper way to code it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are plenty of examples if you google for "android widget tutorial". Two I found useful were:

1. [HelloWidget](http://nm-blog.sanid.com/2009/07/android-hellowidget-tutorial/) from the TheSmilingBlog. Basic tutorial to display an empty box with two buttons.
2. [Creating a Home Screen Widget](http://www.developer.com/ws/article.php/3833306/Creating-a-Home-Screen-App-Widget-on-Android.htm) from developer.com. A more complicated example where it displays an image selected randomly from its collection, with instructions on how to configure the refresh-time as well as buttons on the widget. **EDIT:** Turns out the buttons on the widget are actually in the sequel to that tutorial, and can be found [here](http://www.developer.com/ws/article.php/3837531/Handling-User-Interaction-with-Android-App-Widgets.htm).
3. (I assume you've also read the official tutorial on the [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) website)

Comment: The second link is now dead. Just FYI.

Comment: Apparently both links are now dead. :(

Comment: This post dates back from nearly 4 years ago, I think some dead links are to be expected.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice example:

http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AppWidget/

You can read the [excelent Mark Murph's 'The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development' Book](http://commonsware.com/Android/)

Comment: Good example thanks; that book you recommend does NOT cover AppWidgetProvider/AppWidgetManager stuff.