# Access object in main.xml

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a widget, but I can't access the main.xml elements from the code. If I had an activity, I could use findViewById, but in this case it won't work.

How can I access an element in main.xml from widget?

Comment: You need to use RemoveViews with Widgets.  See this question for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896253/findviewbyid-undefined

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you need as I didn't get why you don't have an activity, please tell me if this is what you want:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null, false);
```

then use findViewById on the view like `myView.findViewById(....)`