# findViewById is undefined for type <my class name is here> in AppWidgetProvider

Tags: android, onclick, listener, undefined, android-appwidget

Is there an equivalent line of code I can use for findViewById ? Eclipse tells me it's undefined for the type  in an AppWidgetProvider.

I'm trying to set up a click handler for the button.

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider implements OnClickListener{

    final Button buttonOnOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_on_off);

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

        /*
         * Set Click Listener
         */
        buttonOnOff.setOnClickListener(this);

        /*
         * The following 3 lines of code are required to display the widget on the screen.
         */
        RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.appwidget_layout);

        ComponentName myWidget = new ComponentName(context,
            WidgetProvider.class);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(myWidget, remoteView);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works rather differently when you're using AppWidgets. Essentially you need to be working with RemoteView rather than traditional Buttons and findViewByIds. See this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858648/android-home-screen-widget-documentation/2864376#2864376) for links on how to write AppWidgets. In particular, the two links for developer.com tutorials.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the link. Truly, Emad