# Android : Application is not installed on your phone (Widget)

Tags: android, widget

I get this error when I'm trying to create the widget from my application onto the home screen.
This is my manifest file for the splash class where I start the Activity :

Splash

```
<activity
    android:name="com.test.me.Splash"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Widget

```
<receiver
    android:name=".Widget"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name= "android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/widget_stuff" />
</receiver>


 <activity
    android:name=".WidgetConfig"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

If I do not put the Activity there the widget would not show up on the widget list. I've tried reinstalling the JDK but I still cant figure out what I'm doing one anybody know how to solve this ?

EDIT : solved it by deleting `android:exported="false"` as it didnt allow activity for external use

Answer (score 1):

[Android home screen widget documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858648/android-home-screen-widget-documentation)

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidWidgets/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some xml layout for your Widget like this.

```
   <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
```

have a look to this [Link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidWidgets/article.html)